# Space between $L^1$ and $BV$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, soft-question, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

I am looking for a function space $X_s$ such that this space has following properties:

1. $X_s$ is a Banach space, and has lower semi-continuous properties with respect to $L^p$ strong convergence.
2. I want $BV\subset X_s\subset L^1$, where $BV$ is the bounded variation space defined in Evans and Gariepy, i.e.,
   $$
   BV(\Omega):=\{u\in L^1(\Omega),\,TV(u,\Omega)<\infty\}
   $$
   where $TV$ denote the total variation.
3. I want $0<s<1$ service as some sort of indictor so that as $s\to 0$,  $X_s\to L^1$ in "some" sense; $s\to 1$ and $X_s\to BV$ in some sense.

I am thinking [Besov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space) space. Would this be a good solution? Any other function space you would recommend? What about BMO space?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the context here? When you say $BV$ I tend to assume you're talking about functions on the line. But (2) implies that $BV\subset L^1$, and that's not true for the usual $BV(\mathbb R)$ and $L^1(\mathbb R)$. Exactly what $BV$ and $L^1$ are you talking about?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich hmm... I think $BV(\mathbb R)\subset L^1(\mathbb R)$ by definition right? Since we are using the norm $\|\cdot\|_{BV}=\|\cdot\|_{L^1}+|Du|_{\mathcal M}$

Comment: No. At least if $BV(\mathbb R)$ means what it usually means, the space of functions of bounded variation. This non-inclusion is obvious. The function $f(t)=1$ has bounded variation. You say "since we're using the norm...". You gave no hint that that's the norm you were talking about. And that is simply _not_ a norm on $BV$. Again, unless you mean something totally different by $BV$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Let me update my post. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Ok, I'll ask again. What is the _context_? I assumed we were talking about functions on $\mathbb R$. You first reply _was_ talking about functions on $\mathbb R$. Now it appears we're talking about functions in $\Omega$. What is $\Omega$? _What is the context_???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry I confused... I just want to talk about functions over open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$...

Comment: They give that definition in the book for an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^N$? I find that hard to believe. There's not, say, an assumption that $\Omega$ is bounded?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I know if we talk about regularity, trace, etc we need bounded domain, and maybe with nice boundary. But for general definition, I think we only need open set, as they did in their book. But yea, feel free to add those assumptions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you're looking for is an interpolation space :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space

I don't remember if these interpolation spaces between $BV$ and $L^1$ are "usual" spaces or not

Comment: Wow, it is a long article. I will read it carefully later. Thank you!

Comment: btw, do you think Besov space will work as this interpolation space?

Comment: @Denoising : Besov spaces are interpolation spaces between $L^p$ and $W^{m,p}$, so I don't think it will be exactly what you want, but I'm not an expert in interpolation spaces